# NoSuchElementException: head of empty list - Scala Maven Plugin

Tags: scala, scala-maven-plugin

I have a scala-project, which I build with Maven via Intellij. Scala version is 2.12.18, Java version is 11. When i build one module, I get error: NoSuchElementException: head of empty list. I read about this error in other scala versions. In some cases it was a compiler bug, in some other it was a programmer fault. My project is big, I use in many places: Nil, Map.empty, etc. Can someone please guide me: if it my fault how can i find the place in code where i made this mistake (list.empty). Or how i can understand, that it's compiler bug. With Maven and scala-compiler-plugin I get only this stack trace without any useful information:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< org.hungryangry.project:module >---------------------
[INFO] Building project 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ builder ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ builder ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (default) @ builder ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[INFO] includes = [**/*.java,**/*.scala,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] /home/hungryangry/Projects/project/module/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 26 source files to /home/hungryangry/Projects/project/module/target/classes at 1697524303646
[ERROR] error: java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:469)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:466)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.ast.TreeGen.mkCastArray(TreeGen.scala:174)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$transformArgs$1(UnCurry.scala:267)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.arrayToSequence$1(UnCurry.scala:263)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transformVarargs$1(UnCurry.scala:313)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transformArgs(UnCurry.scala:333)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$mainTransform$12(UnCurry.scala:487)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:405)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformTrees$1(Trees.scala:2567)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTrees(Trees.scala:2567)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1512)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:57)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformTrees$1(Trees.scala:2567)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTrees(Trees.scala:2567)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$mainTransform$12(UnCurry.scala:487)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:405)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformTrees$1(Trees.scala:2567)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTrees(Trees.scala:2567)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$mainTransform$12(UnCurry.scala:487)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:405)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$2(Trees.scala:1427)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1425)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:57)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.super$transform(UnCurry.scala:473)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$mainTransform$5(UnCurry.scala:473)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:405)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(Trees.scala:2597)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2595)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1468)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.super$transform(TypingTransformers.scala:53)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.$anonfun$transform$1(TypingTransformers.scala:53)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.super$transform(UnCurry.scala:473)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$mainTransform$16(UnCurry.scala:522)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:424)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTemplate(Trees.scala:2571)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$4(Trees.scala:1472)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1471)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:57)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(Trees.scala:2597)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2595)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1468)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.super$transform(TypingTransformers.scala:53)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.$anonfun$transform$1(TypingTransformers.scala:53)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.super$transform(UnCurry.scala:473)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$mainTransform$16(UnCurry.scala:522)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:424)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTemplate(Trees.scala:2571)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$5(Trees.scala:1477)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1476)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:57)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(Trees.scala:2597)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2595)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$7(Trees.scala:1490)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1490)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.super$transform(TypingTransformers.scala:53)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.$anonfun$transform$2(TypingTransformers.scala:55)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.ast.Trees$Transformer.transformUnit(Trees.scala:146)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform$Phase.apply(Transform.scala:37)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:453)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:400)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1509)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1493)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1486)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1615)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:47)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:32)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:67)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.main(Driver.scala:80)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[INFO]  at org_scala_tools_maven_executions.MainHelper.runMain(MainHelper.java:161)
[INFO]  at org_scala_tools_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:26)
[INFO] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[INFO]  at org_scala_tools_maven_executions.MainHelper.runMain(MainHelper.java:161)
[INFO]  at org_scala_tools_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:26)
[INFO] Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:469)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:466)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.ast.TreeGen.mkCastArray(TreeGen.scala:174)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$transformArgs$1(UnCurry.scala:267)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.arrayToSequence$1(UnCurry.scala:263)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transformVarargs$1(UnCurry.scala:313)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transformArgs(UnCurry.scala:333)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$mainTransform$12(UnCurry.scala:487)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:405)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformTrees$1(Trees.scala:2567)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTrees(Trees.scala:2567)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1512)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:57)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformTrees$1(Trees.scala:2567)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTrees(Trees.scala:2567)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$mainTransform$12(UnCurry.scala:487)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:405)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformTrees$1(Trees.scala:2567)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTrees(Trees.scala:2567)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$mainTransform$12(UnCurry.scala:487)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:405)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$2(Trees.scala:1427)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1425)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:57)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.super$transform(UnCurry.scala:473)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$mainTransform$5(UnCurry.scala:473)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:405)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(Trees.scala:2597)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2595)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1468)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.super$transform(TypingTransformers.scala:53)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.$anonfun$transform$1(TypingTransformers.scala:53)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.super$transform(UnCurry.scala:473)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$mainTransform$16(UnCurry.scala:522)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:424)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTemplate(Trees.scala:2571)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$4(Trees.scala:1472)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1471)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:57)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(Trees.scala:2597)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2595)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1468)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.super$transform(TypingTransformers.scala:53)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.$anonfun$transform$1(TypingTransformers.scala:53)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.super$transform(UnCurry.scala:473)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.$anonfun$mainTransform$16(UnCurry.scala:522)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:424)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTemplate(Trees.scala:2571)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$5(Trees.scala:1477)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1476)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:57)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(Trees.scala:2597)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2595)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$7(Trees.scala:1490)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1490)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1400)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2563)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.super$transform(TypingTransformers.scala:53)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.$anonfun$transform$2(TypingTransformers.scala:55)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.mainTransform(UnCurry.scala:525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:121)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.UnCurry$UnCurryTransformer.transform(UnCurry.scala:81)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.ast.Trees$Transformer.transformUnit(Trees.scala:146)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform$Phase.apply(Transform.scala:37)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:453)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:400)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1509)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1493)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1486)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1615)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:47)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:32)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:67)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.main(Driver.scala:80)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)
[INFO]  ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`maven-scala-plugin` is quite old, it's been renamed to `scala-maven-plugin` since then and it's current version (as of 2023) is 4.x: https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/index.html.

**I would upgrade the plugin version** as from the stacktrace it looks like an error happening inside the plugin itself, it's not a compilation error: it's a runtime error in the compilation plugin.

It's probable that the error is caused by a compilation error but as you said you won't be able to find it without the compiler plugin helping you with the relevant line and file.